# Can't open port in digitalocean

Tags: port, digital-ocean, firewall

I’m using digitalocean to host my website and I'm trying to open the port 8832 and 587 without any success. I created a firewall in the control panel and added these to the inbound and outbound rules:

Custom TCP 587 All IPv4 All IPv6

Custom TCP 8832 All IPv4 All IPv6

HTTP    TCP 80  All IPv4 All IPv6

HTTPS   TCP 443 All IPv4 All IPv6

I also disabled ufw in my droplet:

```
ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

I also rebooted the droplet. However it seems to still block the ports 587 and 8832. Interestingly the ports 443 and 80 for the webserver are open. Can someone tell my why I can’t open these specific ports?

this affects the ip: 165.232.76.115

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve it by myself. I had to remove the firewall in the control panel and used the ufw software firewall instead. Don’t know why the control panel firewall didn’t work properly or maybe I used it wrong.